# Changing number in div to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and I'm trying to limit the number in a certain cell or column to 2 decimal places.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to be changing anything. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(".col-product-fee-amount").each(function() {
  this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-product-fee-amount">2.0448</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` elements do not have a value. Instead you need to set their `text()` To do that you can provide a function to `text()` which accepts the current string as an argument which you can then modify as required and return.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".col-product-fee-amount").text(function(i, text) {
    return (parseFloat(text) || 0).toFixed(2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-product-fee-amount">2.0448</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note in the above example the use of `||` to coerce an undefined value to a `0` to prevent errors. Also note the document.ready handler wrapping the jQuery logic. This ensures that the DOM has been loaded before you attempt to interact with it

Comment: Apologies, I copied the wrong code. I need it to change the value of a <td></td> - Do you know how to approach that?

Comment: Interesting. Didn't knew that `.text()` would access a function and loop each element automatically for you. One thing to take into care is if, for some reason, `parseFloat(text)` returns `NaN`, it will display "NaN" instead. It could be desired to convert it to `0.00`.

Comment: @EagleAgency Change the selector. That's all.

Comment: @EagleAgency This code would work in exactly the same way, I presume you just need to change the `.col-product-fee-amount` selector

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel true. In that case use: `return (parseFloat(text) || 0).toFixed(2);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if I change it to <td class="col-product-fee-amount">2.0448</td> it doesn't work. I tried changing "$(".col-product-fee-amount")" to $("td.col-product-fee-amount") with no luck.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh, I know. I'm just saying that just so you add it in the answer, since it is obvious that O.P. is a beginner.

Comment: I updated to show you this working on a `td`, for which it wouldn't need any amendments to the JS. Ensure the `td` is valid in your HTML and there's no errors in the console

Comment: @EagleAgency Make sure that you have the code inside a `jQuery.ready()` event (you may be trying to run the code before the HTML parser even touched on the `<body>`), and that jQuery was loaded correctly.

Comment: It's working on Stackoverflow but not on the live site. The script I'm using is

"<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".product-row .col-product-fee-amount").text(function(i, text) {
    return (parseFloat(text) || 0).toFixed(2);
  });
 });
 </script>"

And the link is https://wholesale.sweetandglory.com/bulk-order/soda-soft-drinks/

Comment: Then most likely you need to add a document.ready handler around the jQuery logic. I've updated the answer again to show you the whole thing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Instead of `$(...)`, please use `jQuery(function($){ ... })` or `jQuery.ready(function($){ ... })`, as somewhere outside the code you can have a stray `jQuery.noConflict()`, which breaks the code. Unlikely on something small, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using JQuery, then that can be achieved by replacing `this.value` with `this.text()` as shown below:

```js
$(".col-product-fee-amount").each(function(){
    $('td').text( parseFloat( $(this).text() ).toFixed(2) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Source data</b>
<div class="col-product-fee-amount">2.0448</div>
<b>Table</b>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Apologies, I copied the wrong code. I need it to change the value of a <td></td> - Do you know how to approach that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to update a table's <td> with the 2-dp value of .col-product-fee-amount ? Just updated the code snippet above to show that -  does this help?